Nuget packages not compatible with net8.0
After cloning a repo, I've failing to build the solution getting build errors regarding some Nuget packages. Here's a list:


error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Graph 5.49.0 is not compatible with    net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package Microsoft.Graph 5.49.0
does not support any target frameworks.
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Graph.Core 3.1.10 is not compatible    with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package Microsoft.Graph.Core
3.1.10 does not support any target frameworks.
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions 1.8.0 is not    compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package
Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions 1.8.0 does not support any target
frameworks.
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure 1.1.4 is    not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package
Microsoft.Kiota.Authentication.Azure 1.1.4 does not support any
target frameworks.
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary 1.3.8 is    not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package
Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary 1.3.8 does not support any
target frameworks.
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Form 1.1.5 is not    compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package
Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Form 1.1.5 does not support any target
frameworks.
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json 1.2.0 is not    compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package
Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json 1.2.0 does not support any target
frameworks.
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Multipart 1.1.3    is not compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package
Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Multipart 1.1.3 does not support any
target frameworks.
error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Text 1.1.4 is not    compatible with net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package
Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Text 1.1.4 does not support any target
frameworks.


What I've tried so far (not necesairally in that order):
Clean the solution (manually as well)
Cleaning Nuget cache
Repair Visual Studio (2022)
Reinstalling Visual Studio (2022)
Reinstalling .NET 8
but I am always get those build errors.
At some point I even got this error message but I cannot reproduce it anymore.

NU1202: Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions 7.4.1 is not
compatible with net8.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0). Package
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions 7.4.1 does not support any target
frameworks.

Notice the windows7 in the last one.
Is there anyone that experienced this before? Why can't I build the project?
Here's the output, in case it's helpful, from the dotnet --info command.
.NET SDK:
 Version:           8.0.204
 Commit:            c338c7548c
 Workload version:  8.0.200-manifests.7d36c14f

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.22631
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\

.NET workloads installed:
There are no installed workloads to display.

Host:
  Version:      8.0.4
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       2d7eea2529

.NET SDKs installed:
  8.0.204 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 8.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:
  Not set

global.json file:
  Not found


Deleted obj and bin folders. Then dotnet restore.

Yeah, that works. This is a VS bug, should be reported. Alternatively, you can switch environment (top left, select Debug and switch to Release or vv, or any other env you have configured). Switching back will then work. Issue has something to do with VS holding a reference open to the obj folder, making it impossible to refresh.

The following combo might also be helpful:

Removing bin and obj folders.
Cleaning Nuget cache: dotnet nuget locals all --clear.
Restoring project: dotnet restore.


My errors were NuGet dependency based errors and I could not resolve the issue in VS 2022. I was able to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore with different versions from 6 to 9 but unable to install other NuGet packages like Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools of compatibles versions. Searched a lot to find the issue, unfortunately I could find any such articles or videos which could resolve my problem.  Luckily I tried clearing the NuGet cache and immediately I could install all its dependencies without any issues.  Thank you
